# How to mark checkboxs generated by loop without ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, checkbox

Im going to do my best to describe my issue, its hard to put into words.

On my page, I have a textbox and a button. I type a users name in the textbox and click the button to bring back all the users information.

Below this, I have a table being generated by a foreach loop of every role in my database that the user could possibly be in, with a 2 checkboxs next to it. The roles and textbox display even before the button is clicked.

When the users information comes back, whichever roles the user is in, I need to check those boxes.

It seems easy enough, I am just having a hard time trying to figure out how I am going to target each specific checkbox, because they are being created in a loop, not allowing me to give them specific ID's.

```
<table border="1" id="ApplicationRoles">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="text-align:center" width="300">Role</th>
                    <th style="text-align:center" width="300">Category 1</th>
                    <th style="text-align:center" width="300">Category 2</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                @foreach (var role in Model.appRoles)
                {
                   <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => role.Name)
                        </td>
                        <td>

                            <input type="checkbox"  />

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" />

                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Using javascript, I can check to see what roles the user is in, but how can I target a specific checkbox to check it(saying the user is in this role), without being able to give each one an ID?

Comment: Use `document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]')` to get a list of all  checkboxes in the document. Of course you'll have to know which checkbox is which!

Comment: @MrLister How could I distinguish which checkbox is which?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way would be to assign for an idea that would make it easier to select via jquery. Since you're using razor. Would look something like this.

```
foreach (var role in Model.appRoles)
{
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk_@(role.Name)" />
}
```

Then when you are trying to get the checkbox you would use a selector like this.

```
$('#chk_' + roleName).prop('checked',true);
```

If you NEEDED to get the checkboxes using strictly jQuery. You could do something like this...

http://jsfiddle.net/8q9cco37/

```
var user = {'role':'ADMIN2'};

var $roleMatch = $('td').filter(function(){
   return $(this).text().toLowerCase() == user.role.toLowerCase();
});

var chk1 = $roleMatch.next('td').find('input');
var chk2 = $roleMatch.next('td').next('td').find('input');

chk1.prop('checked',true);
chk2.prop('checked',true);
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you for including the jquery targeting

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with asp.net, so I may screw up the syntax, but the idea is the same.

Here I'm using role.Name as the ID of the check box, you can use anything convenient to reference to in JS code.

> Role
>                       Category 1
>                       Category 2
>
> ```
>             @foreach (var role in Model.appRoles)
>             {
>                <tr>
>                     <td>
>                         @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => role.Name)
>                     </td>
>                     <td>
>
>                         <input type="checkbox" id="<%= role.Name %>1" />
>
>                     </td>
>                     <td>
>                         <input type="checkbox" id="<%= role.Name %>2"/>
>
>                 </tr>
>             }
>         </tbody>
>     </table>
> ```

Comment: This allows me to give each checkbox a unique id based on the name and category, making it easy to target,perfect, thanks. Your right the syntax is a little off for the id, but I was able to get it.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a variable and attach it as part of the id to distinguish them all. I assume the two inputs are a group per list? So, I would differentiate them within the numbering convention (like 'y' and 'n' if you get what I'm saying):

```
@{
var i = 0;
foreach (var role in Model.appRoles)
{
  i += 1;
  <tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => role.Name)
    </td>
    <td>

        <input type="checkbox" ID="checkbox_Y@i"  />

    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" ID="checkbox_N@i" />
    </td>
  </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to do the actual binding, it would be done like so.

```razor
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.appRoles.Count; i++)
{
      <tr>
          <td>
              @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.appRoles[i].Name)
          </td>
          <td>
              @Html.CheckBoxFor(x=> Model.appRoles[i].IsEnabled, new { id = Model.appRoles[i].MyId })
          </td>
      </tr>
}
```

Then, it would just be a matter of assigning specific IDs if it's something you are interested in.

However, if you wrap that up to an action, it will generate proper names that can be bound back to a model (with a List property) while submitting your form without touching anything.